# Edit link is not working in Json Formatting of view

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have created view using JSON formatting like in below image. The `Give feedback` button is given `editProps` as custom row action. This button works in list view, it opens the edit panel for the selected item.

[image]

But when I add a list webpart on a page then this button doesn't work. `defaultClick` works and it opens a new tab to show current item but editProps does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue related to JSON formatting in SharePoint Online.

Some of the functionalities of JSON are working only in List View and they are not supported when you add the list web part on Site Page.

You can read more about similar issue at: [Column formatting not showing when view shown in a List Web Part (Modern Page and List)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/column-formatting-not-showing-when-view-shown-in-a-list-web-part/m-p/161460).

Also, you can create a new issue at: [SP-Dev-List-Formatting Issues](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/issues).

Comment: Hi @KumarV does this answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.